# Class pointer c#

Tags: c#, pointers

I'm wondering if it's possible in C# to create a class pointer that point to base class. Then you be able to set it to any of the under classes. Like in C++: For example:

```
class Base
{
   virtual void get() = 0;
}
class A : public Base
{
   void get();
}

class B : public Base
{
   void get();
}

main
{
   int i = 0;
   Base *base;

   if(i==0)
      base = new A();
   else
      base = new B();
}
```

Comment: pointer exists in the C# as `unsafe`, but to "point" to the base class, not sure if it is necessary

Comment: `get` is a reserved keyword in c#, don't use it as a method name
Your problem is not clear (to me): just note that simply removing the `* ` in second line of your main will result in a correct c# code (`Base base`);

Comment: Of course you can, but with a reference.

Comment: get is only for this example. Not in actual code.

Comment: You can say `Base base = new A();` in C# and then `base` refers to an instance of `A`. What do you want a pointer for?

Comment: Pointers in C# are unsafe and used for marshalling that is whenever you want to call VC++ stuff from C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C#, all classes are reference types, so you just need to use a normal declaration. In other words, it's as if all the variables of class type are  declared as `classname&` (in C++ terms).

```
namespace Demo
{
    abstract class Base // Abstract means derived classes must implement.
    {
        public abstract void SomeVirtualMethod();
    }

    class Derived1 : Base
    {
        public override void SomeVirtualMethod()
        {
            // Do something.
        }
    }

    class Derived2 : Base
    {
        public override void SomeVirtualMethod()
        {
            // Do something.
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            int i = 0;
            Base b;

            if (i == 0)
                b = new Derived1();
            else
                b = new Derived2();

            b.SomeVirtualMethod();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thx for the easy answer!